# $ \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-x^{2} + sin x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can I calculate the following integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-x^{2} + sin x}dx$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could try expanding the $exp(sin(x))$ term in a series. All the odd powers vanish due to symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got any reason to believe that there is a closed form expression for it? The numerical value comes up to be 2.0671926894979906.

WolframAlpha does not accept the integral when you write it in plain text. I used

> NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2+Sin[x]],{x,-Inf,Inf}]
>   and clicked on
>   Assuming "NIntegrate" is an integral | Use as a math function instead

Or in MATLAB, you'd use

> integral(@(x)exp(-x.^2+sin(x)),-inf,inf)

If you wanted to evaluate this yourself, you could implement midpoint rule, trapezoid rule etc. by hand. Of course math softwares usually have much better algorithms implemented.

Comment: I think it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Actually, the problem comes from my engineering problem. I need to formulate movement of an object. By the way, what kind of software or method did you use to calculate it?

Comment: @Hathanhminh edited my answer